# How do I make my 2nd generation Toyota Hi-Ace start more easily?

Tags: toyota, ignition, diesel

My 2nd generation Toyota Hi-Ace Diesel is not starting easily, or occasionally not starting at all.

I have:
Tested the glow plugs - all quick and fully bright;
Changed battery;
Changed the air filter;
Changed the fuel filter; and
Run Liqui-Moly injector cleaner through, and added Liqui-Moly to diesel.

I think the outside temperature is having an effect but need to be able to overcome this.
My next step is to install new glow plugs in the hope that there is some undetectable fault with the existing ones.
Is this a good idea? Or are there any better ideas out there?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not really an answer for you, but I think replacing the glow plugs is a good next step. Seems like you are going through all the troubleshooting I'd do to get it fixed.

Comment: Like Paulster, not an answer but maybe try cleaning the throttle body as well. Its an easy and simple job.

Comment: OP has not logged in for over a year and a half.  Looks like more info is needed.  OP has never responded to questions.  Going to vote for deletion.